# Find a function $h$ with the following property

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find a function $h$ with the property that

$$h'(x)=6h'(2x)$$

Where $h'(x)=\dfrac{d}{dx}h(x)$.

Comment: From which math text did you pick up the example?

Comment: Any constant function will do $0=0$

Answer (score 2):

Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ gives
$$h(x)=6\cdot\frac{1}{2}h(2x)+C \iff h(x)=3h(2x)+C\,,$$
where $C$ is a constant.

The general solution to this equation is 
$$h(x)=A\cdot3^{-\log_2x}+B\,,$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants.